# Using Firebase for Authentication in iOS app - keep getting error code FIRAuthErrorDomain: 17020 on sign-in, after failure to refresh token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase SDK 3.8 for email/password authentication in my iOS app.  I let the user enter their email/pwd and then I call

```
[[FIRAuth auth] createUserWithEmail:email password:password completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error)
```

Once they successfully authenticate, I use their authentication token to call APIs on my own server.  My server validates the JWT using the logic described in the Firebase Docs to ensure that the token is valid.  Every hour, the token expires and my server returns a 401.  The iOS client then tries to refresh the token:

```
- (void)refreshUserToken:(BOOL)force {
        ...
        [self.firebaseUser getTokenWithCompletion:^(NSString *_Nullable idToken, NSError *_Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                // Handle error
                [self resetAndGoToSignUp];
            } else {
                self.firebaseToken = idToken;
                ...
            }
        }];
```

}

The resetAndGoToSignUp function does this:

```
// Sign out Firebase User
NSError *error;
BOOL status = [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&error];
if (!status) {
    // show user alert
    ...
}
// go to my sign up page
AppDelegate *appDelegateTemp = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegateTemp.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SignUp" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

At this point, when the user enters their email/password, the firebase createUserWithEmail API always returns:

```
FirAuthErrorDomain: 17020
```

This is supposed to be a temporary network error, but it continues to return the same error.  I even tried deleting and re-installing the app to start from scratch and the API continues to return the same thing.  So essentially, once the user fails to refresh the token, it seems like they can never get back into my app.  (Perhaps deleting/reinstalling wouldn't resolve anything if the token and credentials are stored in the Keychain).  On first launch, when I detect based on NSUserDefaults that you haven't used the app before, I also call this code to ensure you're signed out:

```
// Sign out Firebase User here
NSError *error;
BOOL status = [[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&error];
```

But that doesn't seem to help.  I still get error 17020.  I must be doing something incorrectly in the order I am calling the Firebase APIs.  Has anyone run into this and found a resolution?

In case it helps, this is happening on at least two different devices - iPad and iPhone6s, one is running iOS 10.2 and the other is running iOS 9.3.5

**UPDATE - RESOLVED**

The reason I was getting 17020 over and over is that I had denied Cellular Data permission to my app as part of executing another series of tests, and also was not on wifi.  Once I re-enabled cellular data, I was able to log in.  :-/